# I want to make a counter but i don't know what i'm missing or am doing wrong

Tags: button

this is the code i made but it gives me an error about te } and also i need to know how to make delays with this

```
int ledPin = 4;
int buttonPin=2;
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  if (buttonPin=(LOW);
 {
 Serial.println("someone pressed it");
}
  else
  {
    Serial.println("nothing");
  }
}
```

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot bracket here

```
if (buttonPin=(LOW);
```

Should be

```
if (digitalRead(buttonPin)==(LOW)){
```

To make a delay of 0.5 seconds for example:

```
delay(500);
```